# s3cmd sync with boto in python

Tags: python, boto, s3cmd

I'm trying to move some back up scripts from bash to python, for better error handling.

I have been using [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) sync to back up directories to s3. I was hoping to find a similarly simple way to do this directly in python (probably with boto), but so far it seems simplest to just use `subprocess.call` and keep using s3cmd.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

With boto alone, there isn't a very easy method. There are several packages floating around that provide this function, and they all seem to use the same method: **compare the local file's MD5 hash to the [S3 key's etag](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.key)**.

Here's how to compute the MD5 hash of a local file (note: loads entire contents of file into memory):

```
print hashlib.md5(open(filename, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
```

> 7bee81f4be312203c0e29d4dfe65fb0b

And for an S3 key (note: you must not create a `boto.s3.key.Key` locally; instead get it from the bucket):

```
key = bucket.get_key(path)
print key.etag
```

> "7bee81f4be312203c0e29d4dfe65fb0b"

Note that for some reason, the etag is surrounded by quote characters.

To perform the sync, simply check if the MD5 and etag are different before doing the get/put.